# Facebook Stetho: Nothing shown, D/ChromeDevtoolsServer﹕ Method not implemented: Not implemented: null

Tags: android, facebook, google-chrome-devtools, stetho

I am trying to use Facebook Stetho library in my application. As far as I know, I have done the setup:

- I have a custom Application class.
- I have a debug Application class that extends the aforementioned one and initializes Stetho.
- I have a debug manifest that specified that the debug Application should replace the standard one.

However, I am seeing nothing in the CDT and I get quite a few of these in the IDE out console:

```
com.example.packagename D/ChromeDevtoolsServer﹕ Method not implemented: Not implemented: null
```

I can't happend to find anything about it around.

Comment: It sounds like Stetho may not have been initialized correctly, but it's hard to tell for sure without seeing the code. From this issue, it seems like the "method not implemented" errors might not be relevant: https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/80

Comment: Definitively some bug. Same code with version 1.1.0 is working fine. No more error messages either.

Answer (score -1):

I found this:

https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/42

TL;DR: If you are using proguard add this to your config:

`-keep class com.facebook.stetho.** {*;}`

Comment: This should not (and effectively is not) make a difference, as I was not using ProGuard.